# Jquery only targeting clicked classes parent not others?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to my menu element to display a submenu when I click on child button. But I also have identical html and classes on other menu elements. So when I press a button it opens all submenus and closes the open ones.

I want it to work so that when I click a button, only his parents submenu opens and closes if clicked.

```
<ul>
  <li class="menu-item current-menu-item">
    <a href="">Menu1</a>
    <button>click</button>
       <ul class="submenu">
        <li>asdasd</li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item">
    <a href="">Menu2</a>
    <button>click</button>
       <ul class="submenu">
        <li>asdasd</li>
      </ul>
  </li>
    <li class="menu-item">
    <a href="">Menu3</a>
    <button>click</button>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li>asdasd</li>
      </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

.submenu {
  display: none;
}
.current-menu-item .submenu {
  display: block;
}

$(".menu-item button").click(function(){
  $(".menu-item button").parent('.menu-item').toggleClass("current-menu-item");
});
```

http://codepen.io/rKaiser/pen/QKgQVQ

Thank you.

Comment: Use `$(this)` instead `$(".menu-item button")` in click event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".menu-item button").click(function(){
  $(this).parent('.menu-item').toggleClass("current-menu-item");
});
```

otherwise the jQuery selector finds all elements with the class .menu-item button